# Requirements eclipse update site

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'd like to know how to add th required plugins to the eclipse update site. In other words, I've packed my plugins in a feature project, and then I've created an update site. When I try to install the plugin from another machine, I got this:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.


 Software being installed: X-MAN Tool 2.0.0 (xman.eclipse.feature.feature.group 2.0.0)
  Missing requirement: X-MAN Tool 2.0.0 (xman.eclipse.feature.feature.group 2.0.0) requires 'org.eclipselabs.spray.runtime.graphiti 0.5.1' but it could not be found
```

Where should I add those depencies? I'd like to highlitght the fact that the plugin  org.eclipselabs.spray.runtime.graphiti 0.5.1 is alredy listed in the dpeencies list (see picture).

Many thanks for your attention

Simone

[image]

Comment: what if you declare the plugin in the `plug-ins` tab ? so that it will be packaged with it

Comment: Check after exporting/building repository/update site whether it has `org.eclipselabs.spray.runtime.graphiti` plugin in it(in plugin folder) and verify its version MANIFEST.xml file